# Wrong column width when using table-layout:fixed

Tags: html, css, html-table

In my [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jur4x/rKQrJ/2/) I have two HTML tables. They are basically the same - same class, same content, everything. The only difference is the order of rows.

```
<style>
.tbl-lay-fixed {table-layout:fixed}
</style>

<table class="tbl-lay-fixed" border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td width="5%">xxxx</td>
      <td width="95%">yyyyyyyyyy</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2" width="100%">xxxx</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<table class="tbl-lay-fixed" border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2" width="100%">xxxx</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="5%">xxxx</td>
      <td width="95%">yyyyyyyyyy</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Table number 1 is displayed correctly - width of the cells is correct.

Table number 2 is displayed incorrectly - second row have two columns with witdh set as 5% and 95% accordingly, but instead it is displayed as 50% 50%.

[image: Problem with table-layout:fixed;]

Where is the problem? It is the same in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work in Firefox at least
(changing bottom TD colspan to 20)

```
just remove "width="100%" <table class="tbl-lay-fixed" border="1" width="100%"> from the table class
```

Comment: Well, in Chorme it looks wrong, and adding `colspan="20"` is just killing the table stucture, because I dont have 20 cells in second row...

Comment: wait --> just remove "width="100%" <table class="tbl-lay-fixed" border="1" width="100%"> from the table class

Comment: But what if I need that width of the table?

Comment: hmm does it have to be a % ?

Comment: As a solution - min-width:100% can be used.

Comment: ok , will use in future (although is min-width browser compatible?)